# Automatically adding users to roster using Smack API

Tags: java, client, xmpp, smack, instant-messaging

I am building a client application for Intra Office Messaging System using Openfire as server. Using Roster class I can find the list of buddies (friends/contacts) using:

```
Roster rs= con.getRoster();
Collection<RosterEntry> list=rs.getEntries();
System.out.println("\n\n" + list.size() + " buddy(ies):");
for (RosterEntry r : list) {
    System.out.println(r.getName());
}
```

But since this is an IOMS (Intra Office Messaging System), the requirement is diferent. There is no need to add contact. All users should see every other user and his status. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please try to find a better/more descriptive title for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to integrating your openfire with AD. Add all users in a single common group and then import that group in the client. That way a user will automatically appear as a member of that group, and his/her online status will be available to all members of that group. And make sure whenever a new user is added, it becomes member of this group. This way everybody is imported at once in user's list.

Here is a reference link regarding same: [Openfire Automatic Roster Population via Shared Groups](http://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1619) and here is the guide to [integrate Openfire with LDAP](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/ldap-guide.html)

Another way would be to update Openfire code and change registration process to add code for automatically adding all users to buddy list of the newly registered user. You can also do the same code on client side. But this is not a good path to walk on, as it will cause problem as the number of users in system grows.

Comment: I am thinking of an alternative. Is it possible to broadcast a message to all users who are registered irrespective of whether they are in the buddy list of the user or not?

Comment: @stalin consider using the broadcast plugin.

Comment: I have decided to do this: There is a "registration plugin" plugin for openfire server using which we can set the default group to which every user must be added as soon as he is registered and this solves my problem!